# csv stream parser ( papaparse ) is blocking render?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-streaming, papaparse

I'm using papa parse to retrieve csv streams from my backend for data visualization , however I noticed that even though it is calling the callback for the data chunks properly it is also blocking render. I'm trying to add new data to my graphs as it comes it but it doesn't seem to be able to do so.

Anyone have experience with this? Or perhaps know what is blocking the render?

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour in PapaParse is to run the parsing job in the main thread (also the UI thread) of the browser. But there's an option to avoid this.

In the PapaParse configuration enable 'workers'

http://papaparse.com/docs#config

That will run the parsing job in another thread using the WebWorkers API available in modern browsers, and will not block the UI thread.

More information about PapaParse workers here: http://papaparse.com/faq#workers

Comment: I had the service worker enabled and is tested on a browser with support for the technology.

Comment: Can you add an example code to reproduce the problem?